# Is there a simple python script for xpub generation from private key

Tags: private-key, public-key, python, xpub

I need a python script to verify, in an air gapped system, that my 24-word (or 12-word) mnemonic seed indeed generates the xpub that my wallet is showing me.

Is there a simple script that does that, having minimal dependencies?

**UPDATE:**

based on the answer below using https://github.com/trezor/python-mnemonic, I did

```
def main() -> None:
    import sys
    m = Mnemonic("english")
    seed = Mnemonic.to_seed("my 12 words")
    pubkey = Mnemonic.to_hd_master_key(seed)
    print(pubkey)
```

but I get

```
xprv...
```

and no pubkey.

How do I get the master pub key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this](https://github.com/mcdallas/cryptotools) library which is a pure python library with no dependencies (disclaimer: I am the author)

```
>>> from cryptotools import Xprv

>>> xprv = Xprv.from_mnemonic('assist excess fox blossom trouble cry must segment arrive stereo weather april pudding tuna change')

>>> xpub = xprv.to_xpub()

>>> xpub.encode()
'xpub661MyMwAqRbcGSaJ8ymCnwWbZzUgRB9XSAGoAvJc92oorJqzfyTPNQCEzqetVjofVs6DjXEPgR62vGP8UsSL4HFXLcRHdBbcDZ7DgyZea59'
```

Comment: is it possible to convert the xpub to ypub and zpub?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs yes try adding the parameter `addresstype='P2WPKH-P2SH'` or `addresstype='P2WPKH'` in the `from_mnemonic()` method

Comment: shouldn't the method `to_xpub` be called `to_pubkey` then? `xpub` is a little misleading

Comment: I'm getting `cannot import name 'Xprv' from cryptotools` on my raspberry pi. Any thoughts on that? Thank you very much

Comment: Did you install the wrong library perhaps? Dont do pip install cryptotools thats a different kibrary

Comment: I cloned from git and placed into the raspberry pi sd card to later install it, there's no internet on the rpi

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'd say the simplest way is to use python bip39 implementation of trezor, this [one file](https://github.com/trezor/python-mnemonic/blob/master/mnemonic/mnemonic.py) should be enough with methods:

`to_seed` - to convert list of the words into seed and

`to_hd_master_key` - to generate master xpub/xpriv

It doesn't support further derivations (which require a bit more dependencies), for which I'd suggest using [bip32](https://github.com/darosior/python-bip32/blob/master/bip32/bip32.py) library.

Comment: I did `
def main() -> None:
    import sys
    m = Mnemonic("english")
    seed = Mnemonic.to_seed("my 12 words")
    pubkey = Mnemonic.to_hd_master_key(seed)
    print(pubkey)`

Comment: but I got only `xprv9s2...`. What am I missing?

Comment: I did an update, please take a look

Comment: I think it does not generate master pubkey, only priv key.

Answer (score 1):

The following code using the [python-bip32](https://github.com/darosior/python-bip32) lib can show this information.

```
from bip32 import BIP32, HARDENED_INDEX

bip32 = BIP32.from_seed(bytes.fromhex("01"))

# get master xpriv and xpub
master_xpriv = bip32.get_master_xpriv()
master_xpub = bip32.get_master_xpub()

print("master_xpriv: " + master_xpriv)
print("master_xpub: " + master_xpub)

# get from specif path 
xpriv_from_path = bip32.get_xpriv_from_path("m/84'/0'/0'/0/1")
xpub_from_path = bip32.get_xpub_from_path("m/84'/0'/0'/0/1")

print("xpriv_from_path: " + xpriv_from_path)
print("xpub_from_path: " + xpub_from_path)
```